# Ошибка при отображении CardView

Tags: java, android

Пользуюсь intellij idea, хотя в  android-studio то же самое, проверял(все IDE последних версий).
Сама суть проблемы: хотя я думаю, что библиотека подключенна к проекту, при попытке сделать карточку (CardView) в визуальном редакторе возникает ошибка :

> Rendering Problems:
>      The following classes could not be instantiated:
>       - android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Стэктрейс ошибки:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.cardview.R$styleable
>           at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.load(ProjectClassLoader.java:124)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:53)
>           at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:81)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.initialize(CardView.java:203)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.(CardView.java:101)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>           at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
>           at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:176)
>           at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:214)
>           at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:142)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
>           at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:413)
>           at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
>           at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:709)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:698)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:698)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:817)
>           at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>           at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>           at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Кроме того, когда я запускаю приложение на телефоне, экран, где у меня CardView, не открывается, приложение вылетает.
Стэктрейс ошибки в logcat при запуске приложения:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>               at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
>               at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2308)
>               at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
>               at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
>               at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
>               at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2132)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>               at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2035)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1792)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1047)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                   at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
>                   at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
>                   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2308)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
>                   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2132)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>                   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2035)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1792)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1047)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.cardview.R$styleable
>               at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.initialize(CardView.java:203)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.(CardView.java:101)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                   at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
>                   at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
>                   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2308)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
>                   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2132)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>                   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2035)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1792)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1047)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cardView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/view_fragment4" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/image_4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/twitter"
                android:onClick="onCLickTwitter" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view4">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"

                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/view_fragment4" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/image_1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/vk"
                android:onClick="onCLickVK" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view5">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"

                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/view_fragment4" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/image_3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/fb"
                android:onClick="onCLickFacebook" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view4"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:background="@drawable/separator1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view5"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"

            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view4"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:background="@drawable/separator1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Покажите XML, где этот CardView у вас.

Comment: @pavlofff, добавил в вопрос. Извините, что не сразу..)

Comment: @pavlofff , беру библиотеку-копирую ее в паку libs, правой кнопкой мыши-add as library. Всегда так добавлял .jar файлы, все работает..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На ошибки,которые выдает визуальный редактор разметки стоит не обращать внимания вовсе, эти ошибки никаким образом не влияют ни на что, кроме как на вид в самом редакторе разметки.
К сожалению, отображение даже некоторых стандартных виджетов дается ему с трудом, кастомные же он отобразить вовсе не в силах.
Там есть такой крестик над сообщением о ошибке  вверху слева - смело нажимайте на него - это решит вашу проблему единственным надежным способом.

Будем надеятся, что когда-нибудь JetBrains или Google решат этот вопрос и визуальный редактор станет лучше.

По поводу того, что приложение падает при попытке отображения `CardView` стэктрейс при падении указывает на то, что библиотека у вас все же не подключена.
Для того, чтобы добавить класс-виджет `CardView` в свой проект, необходимо в файле `build.gradle` модуля-приложения добавить следующие зависимости (версии библиотек актуальны для текущей даты) :

```
 dependencies {

   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1' }
```

Comment: я слегка изменил текст вопроса. Ошибка не только в отображении.

Comment: спасибо вам огромное, сейчас все отображается)) огроооомное

Answer (score 2):

Проблема не в CardView. Посмотрите на стек

```
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.load(ProjectClassLoader.java:124)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:53)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:81)
...
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
```

больше похоже на конфликты между idea и андроидовским сдк. Наверное нужно на на студию перейти и обновить инструменты и студию.

Comment: у меня есть студия, только что пробовал, то же самое

Comment: У меня последняя версия android sdk

Comment: @DenShDen, но в стеке то пишет at com.android.tools.idea.rendering . Проверьте настройки превью для layout, у меня там Best Fit или как-то так установлено. (Шаманизм конечно.)